# Getting PC-lint to work with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++-2012, pc-lint

Did anyone got Gimpel's PC-Lint 9.00j to parse the include files of Visual Studio 2012 without spewing out hundreds of bogus errors?

A subset of settings I am using (the full ones give the exact same results):

```
-u
+linebuf
-i"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include"
-i"C:\Program Files (x86)\lint"
co-msc110.lnt
```

Gives me 325 errors when I try to lint the following one-liner:

```
#include <vector>
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

The following seems to have done it:

```
-emacro((1??), _VARIADIC_EXPAND_*)
-emacro((10??), _VARIADIC_EXPAND_*)
-emacro(39, _VARIADIC_EXPAND_*)
-emacro(26, _HAS_TRIVIAL_COPY)
-etemplate(1013)
-esym(78, _Ty)
-elib(63)
```